# save null value after data validation is used

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC  but however I'm having a problem that validation is not working. It saves blank data in database.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Define "not working".  What is it doing?  What are you expecting it to do?  Why?

Comment: @Uddyan Semwal Can you specify your problem in more details?

Comment: working fine as saves data in the db but if value is null and saves the data vaidation is not working in this case its saving null values in the database

Comment: @David validation of input field is not working when we not filling the value in input field its saving null value in db

Comment: @UddyanSemwal: If your validation logic isn't working as expected then the first thing you'll want to do is debug your validation logic.  Which isn't shown here in the question.  The most important part of my earlier comment is the "Why" part.  *Why* do you expect your code to not save a `null` value for this field?  There is exactly *zero* code in the question which (a) validates input or (b) saves to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `required` in your model or in your html.

Because the programs warns you only if you write letters in a box which expects numbers for example.

Hope this help

Leo

Comment: @UddyanSemwal can mark the question as answer if it resolve the problem